# YAML Autocomplete from enum Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, yaml

I have YAML file that has a list, the values allowed in that list are defined in an Enum in that project.

Is there anyway I can help the user with autocompletion when opening the file in intellij? I know Spring boot to do this in some way.

Comment: Try this: go to this link, and add the same maven dependency http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor - then try running `mvn clean install` either through the IDE or CMD, it should generate the metadata needed for IDEs to autocomplete properties files

Answer (score 0):

Such auto completion is currently not provided in YAML configuration files, but .properties files only. Please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151708 for progress.